# multiple validation errors showing up for single property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, validation

i'm often getting multiple errors showing up for an individual property, when I'd like them to be prioritized, as in, if **Required** is satisfied, check **StringLength**, but if Required fails, show that message only.  I'm getting inconsistent behavior here, and I'm curious as to how the framework determines this priority?

has anyone else had problems with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unsure on this one but I'd be thinking of a custom model binder.

Comment: is it default behavior for all failed errors to show?  by that I mean, if I have one property "Message" and two validation attributes attached to it in the model, should both errors show if they both fail, or just the first one?